# JSON to abap internal table

Tags: json

Could you please help me to code this : Want to recieve a json file and convert into abap internal table.
json file structure will be unknown. i mean the tags can not be in order. 
json file structure:

```
{
    "recurringPaymentInfo":
        {
            "id":"a889898989",
            "referanceNumber":76556,
            "activityIndicator":"NEW",
            "channel":"agent",
            "cancelRecurring":false,
            "stopPay":false,
            "authorizationType":"",
            "agentEmail":"",
            "maxAmount":"",
            "customer":
            {
                "phoneNumber":"5345",
                "email":"test.test@test.com",
                "address":
                    {
                        "line1":"87,okhle street",
                        "city":"woodlandHills",
                        "country":"usa",
                        "zipCode":91367                 
                    },
                "paymentMethod":
                    {
                        "requestReasonType":"EFT/PC/CC",
                        "accountHolderName":"abc",
                        "BankRoutingNumber":3434,
                        "bankName":"chase",
                        "cardNumber":3424234,                       
                        "cardtype":"visa/master/amex",
                        "cardStartDate":11414124,
                        "cardToDate":24242412,
                        "region":"CA"
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I Want to recieve a json file and convert into abap internal table. json file structure will be unknown. i mean the tags can not be in order. json file structure: